# How to select id from a single form

Tags: jquery

I have this

```
$('#edit-preview') .addClass("popup");
$('#edit-submit') .addClass("nopopup");
$('#edit-save-to-sandbox') .addClass("sandboxnopopup");
$("#node-form").attr('target', '_blank');

$('.nopopup').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevents the default submit action
    $("#node-form").removeAttr('target').submit().attr('target', '_blank');
});

$('.sandboxnopopup').click(function(e) {
    $("#node-form").removeAttr('target');
});
```

but now ALL button that have input id=edit-submit or edit-preview have the same function... i want to do it only for edit-submit or edit-preview IN #node-form... can someone help? sorry for my english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warning! IDs should be unique in a whole html document.

You can't have two inputs with the same ID. It's bad because!

Hard to find documentation about this because it's one of the most basic concepts of HTML in the first place.

Use classes!

Anyways, to select only children of an element you can do this:

```
$('#edit-preview, #edit-submit', $('#node-form'))
```

Which should now be

```
$('.edit-preview, .edit-submit', $('#node-form'))
```

Since you're using classes to identify semantically similar elements now ;-)

Comment: You are not paying attention... (shaking head and sighing) ;-)